What could be the potential risk of installing this "ATB" handlebar on a road bike?
I recently bought this "Nitto X Crumbworks KT Bar" handlebar to replace the one on my bike. I wanted it to have a more upright sitting position and I also just liked the style. Nitto seems to be a reputable manufacturer of bike parts and this handlebar specifically is frequently touted online. However, after opening the box I noticed the plastic packaging has this disclaimer:

This handlebar is designed to use on ATB.
Do not use this bar with road bike aluminum stems.
The stem sags and it is dangerous to ride.

This warning is confusing to me. I would think an ATB bike would be exposed to more stresses than a road bike. Is the warning more about having an aluminum stem? What could potentially happen if you use this handlebar with a "road bike aluminum stem"? What is it exactly that this disclaimer is warning against?
I have this bike currently, and it looks like the stem that comes with it is "Marin Alloy" which is probably aluminum. Can I just switch the stem to a steel stem? For what it's worth, I heard that my specific bike can make for an excellent ATB bike from online videos and blogs (even though Marin advertises it as a commuter bike). I didn't really care for that too much. But in any case, does that mean this bike is okay with this handlebar?


It's due to clamp diameter.
MTBs/ATBs/whatever-you-call-them always have 25.4mm stem unless they have one of the oversized stems.
Road bikes at the ~25mm stem sizes generally used 26.0mm stem.
If you attach a handlebar designed for 25.4mm clamp into a bike with 26.0mm stem, it is not securely attached.
Measure the external diameter of your road bike style handlebar near the stem (at the ends it has a different diameter). Since it's a road bike, it most likely is 26.0mm. If this is the case, it's unsafe to attach a handlebar designed for 25.4mm stems.
However, theoretically it's possible to find 25.4mm stem on a road bike. I know this since I have several road bike drop bars for 25.4mm clamps. They are not extinct in the wild, but probably rarer than 26.0mm clamp areas.
If your stem and old handlebar are 26.0mm, all you need to do is to buy a 25.4mm stem.

Aha so that is what the warning is about. My bike actually has a 31.8mm stem and I planned for that by also buying a 25.4 to 31.8mm shim. That should be fine for this right?

I think shim is a somewhat nonideal approach, I would prefer a stem of the correct size. It probably doesn't immediately fail, but could be weaker than correctly sized stem.

@juhist A shim (if it is tubular) may as well be stronger, preventing load spikes at the edges and effectively increasing wall thickness.

Modern mountain bikes moved on to 31.8 mm clamp diameters many years ago and have since adopted (unfortunately) 35 mm diameters.

@juhist how does this answer address the warning’s statement that the “stem sags”. I don’t think this warning is about clamp diameters at all.
